# is it good programming style to use infinite loop to scan and update output signal

Tags: verilog

my code is as follows:

```
  module command_FSM(sys_R_Wn,sys_ADSn,cState,sys_REF_REQ,sys_REF_ACK,sys_INIT_DONE,sys_CLK);

 input sys_R_Wn;
 input sys_CLK;
 input sys_ADSn;
 output  [4:0] cState;
 inout sys_INIT_DONE;
 input sys_REF_REQ;
 output sys_REF_ACK;

 wire sys_R_Wn;
 wire sys_ADSn;
 reg [4:0] cState;
 wire sys_INIT_DONE;
 wire sys_REF_REQ;
 reg sys_REF_ACK;
 reg mjet;
 integer i;

 parameter c_idle=5'b10000;
 parameter c_AR=5'b10001;
 parameter c_tRFC=5'b10010;
 parameter c_rdata=5'b10011;
 parameter c_tDAL=5'b10100;
 parameter c_cl=5'b10101;
 parameter c_ACTIVE=5'b10110;
 parameter c_wdata=5'b10111;
 parameter c_REDA=5'b11000;
 parameter c_tRCD=5'b11001;
 parameter c_WRITEA=5'b11010;

 initial 
 begin
 cState=c_idle;
 end

 initial
 begin
 for(i=0;;i=i+1)
 begin
 #2;  
 if (sys_INIT_DONE==1'b1)
 if(~sys_REF_REQ && ~sys_ADSn)
 begin
 case (cState)


 5'b10000: begin
            cState=c_ACTIVE;
            #10;
            end


  5'b10110:
           if(sys_R_Wn)
           begin 
           cState=c_tRCD;
           #10;
           cState=c_REDA;
           end
           else
           begin
           cState=c_tRCD;
           #10;
           cState=c_WRITEA;
           end




  5'b11000: begin
            cState=c_cl;
            end

  5'b10101: begin
            cState=c_rdata;
            end

  5'b11010: begin
            cState=c_wdata;
            end

  5'b10111: begin
            cState=c_tDAL;
            end
            endcase
            end
            end
            end 

     always @(posedge sys_REF_REQ)
     begin
     sys_REF_ACK=1;
     case(cState)
     5'b10000: begin
          cState=c_AR;
          #50;
          cState=c_idle;
          end
     endcase
     end
     endmodule
```

here i want  "cState" signal to be scanned and updated continuously based on statemachines.Firstly i tried always @* but as it had only output signal cState to be updated.So that block  was executed only once because it had no input signal that was being modified in that always @* block.So my doubt is is it good thing to use "infinite for loop" to serve that purpose of scanning and updating continuously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no; it is not good style to implement FSMs using an infinite loop.

The long answer is that it very much depends. Firstly, if this FSM is purely for a functional model in simulation and never to be synthesized for an FPGA or ASIC; you might use an infinite loop to implement an FSM. However, you should use the keyword `forever` to implement these loops, not `for (i = 0; ; i = i + 1)` or `while (1)`. Or, if they are clocked, you can use an `always @(posedge clk)` or the like to trigger them (or use `forever begin @(posedge clk)` if its a forked process or something fancy like that).

However, based on the header of this module, it appears you want to make a synthesizable FSM, it which case, theres quite a lot you need to do to fix your code. Heres a short list of suggestions to make your code synthesizable and have better style:

- As a general rule, do not use `initial` blocks inside an module. While they have a few limited uses (in FPGA synthesis), you should fully understand those uses before using them. If you need a variable to take on an initial state, use a reset line in the element storing that variable (see the next point)
- Combinational logic should be placed in an `always @*` block and sequential logic should be placed in an `always @(posedge clk[, negedge rstL])` block (the reset is optional). When making a state machine, I recommend the following style:

```
reg state, next_state;
```

// The register that holds the state
always @(posedge clk, negedge rstL) begin
  if (~rstL) begin
    state <= INIT; // Your starting state here
  end
  else begin
    state <= next_state;
  end 
end

// The logic that determines the next state and output values based on the inputs and current state
always @* begin
  // Defaults
  [ Place your outputs here with some default value ]

next_state = state; // As selfloops are common, I typically just set the next state to be the current state

case (state)
    [ Your logic for what to do in each state here ]
  endcase
end

This form I find to be the best to ensure no latches and makes the synthesis tools happy with simple register blocks (the `always @(posedge clk)` block).

- Using parameters for state names is good practice, but you should use them everywhere, even in the case statement, like:

```
case (state)
  INIT: begin
    ...
  end
  READ: begin
    ...
  end
endcase
```

- Do not use delays in your combinational logic like `x = 1'b0; #10; x = 1'b1;`. You change `cState` like this in your `initial` block but really should have different logic for each state.
- You declare `sys_REF_REQ` as an inout when it should probably be an input.
- Don't trigger logic on non-clock things, like `always @(posedge sys_REF_REQ)`. Only use posedge and negedge on clocks and resets within synthesizable code.

Thats all I see right now, but other might add more in the comments. Best of luck!