# SystemVerilog error: "already exists; must not be redefined as a named block"

Tags: system-verilog

I'm creating a state machine with implicit datapath and am getting three errors that I haven't been able to resolve.

For the endcase error, I've made sure that all the begins have a corresponding end in the always block.

For the Finish error, the state has only been defined once so I'm not sure about that.

For the ; error, I have no idea why it doesn't want me to include countx and county statements.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
module fillscreen(input logic clk, input logic rst_n, input logic [2:0] colour,
                  input logic start, output logic done,
                  output logic [7:0] vga_x, output logic [6:0] vga_y,
                  output logic [2:0] vga_colour, output logic vga_plot);

     enum logic [1:0] {Load = 2'b00, Increment = 2'b01, Out = 2'b10, Finish = 2'b11} state, next_state;
     logic [7:0] countx, county;


     always @ (posedge clk) begin

        case(state)

        Load:
               if(rst_n == 0) 
                next_state <= Load; 
            else if (start == 1) 
                next_state <= Increment;
            else begin
            next_state <= Load; end
        //initialize counter
        countx <= 0;    
        county <= 0;

        Increment: 
            if(rst_n == 0) 
                next_state <= Load;
            else if (county < 119 && countx < 159) begin
                county <= county+1; 
                next_state <= Increment; end                
            else if (countx < 159) begin
                countx <= countx +1;
                next_state <= Increment; end
            else 
                next_state <= Finish;

        //output            
        vga_y <= county;
        vga_x <= countx;
        vga_colour <= countx % 8;           
        vga_plot <= 1;

        Finish: 
            done <= 1;          
            if(rst_n == 0) 
                next_state <= Load; 
            else begin
                next_state = Finish; end
        Default: 
            vga_y <= county;
            vga_x <= countx;
            done <= 0;
            vga_plot <= 0;
        endcase
    end
endmodule
```

Here are the  errors I'm getting:

```
** Error: fillscreen.sv(22): near ";": syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ':'
** Error: fillscreen.sv(54): near "endcase": syntax error, unexpected endcase
** Error: fillscreen.sv(25): 'Increment' already exists; must not be redefined as a named block
** Error fillscreen.sv(43): 'Finish' already exists; must not be redefined as a named block
```

Answer (score 0):

For any case, you need to include `begin..end` if the code block for that case has multiple lines, just like if-statements or always blocks (see comments inline, there more than just missing `begin..end`):

```
case(state) // <- Note, you never assign state, only next_state, might want to review your code for correctness
  Load: begin // <- This case has multiple lines
    if (rst_n == 0) begin // <- I do begin..end for EVERYTHING as I inevitably come back and add lines in the body which can lead to bugs if there is no begin..end, like {..} in C
      next_state <= Load;
    end
    else if (start == 1) begin
      next_state <= Increment;
    end
    else begin
      next_state <= Load;
    end
    //initialize counter
    countx <= 0;    
    county <= 0;
  end
  Increment: begin
    if (rst_n == 0) begin
      next_state <= Load;
    end
    else if (county < 119 && countx < 159) begin
      county <= county+1; 
      next_state <= Increment;
    end                
    else if (countx < 159) begin
      countx <= countx +1;
      next_state <= Increment;
    end
    else begin
      next_state <= Finish;
    end

    //output            
    vga_y <= county;
    vga_x <= countx;
    vga_colour <= countx % 8;           
    vga_plot <= 1;
  end
  Finish: begin
    done <= 1;          
    if (rst_n == 0) begin
      next_state <= Load; 
    end
    else begin
      next_state <= Finish; // Should be non-blocking
    end
  end
  default: begin // <- Should be lower-case "default"
    vga_y <= county;
    vga_x <= countx;
    done <= 0;
    vga_plot <= 0;
  end
endcase
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Regarding the state machine, I forgot to assign state = next_state. Is is possible to include this in the same always block, or should does it have to be assigned in a separate D flip flop module?

Comment: @JamesDean it can be (remember, needs to be `state <= next_state` if its supposed to be in a register), but that will mean the transition will be delayed as `next_state` is assigned via non-blocking assignment. Typically, you would assign `next_state` in a combinational block (`always_comb` or `always @(*)`) and assigned using blocking assignment (`=`) then have a simple clocked block: `always @(posedge clk) begin state <= next_state; end` to separate combinational logic from the actual FFs.

Comment: Style can be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28925953/is-it-good-programming-style-to-use-infinite-loop-to-scan-and-update-output-sign/28936372#28936372 (See second bullet point)